# How to pass value to file being called in include_once

Tags: php

When i tried to pass a value $abc to the IncludedFile.php, it doesnt go through. Neither does the $session work. Is there a way to pass a value to the IncludedFile.php? My ultimate aim is to get the calculation processed at the IncludedFile.php and then echo it on the Main.php

**Main.php**

```
<?php $abc = 'abc';
include_once ('IncludedFile.php'); 
echo $answer; ?>
```

**IncludedFile.php**

```
<?php if($abc=='abc') {$answer = 5;} ?>
```

Comment: There's something else going wrong there.Your `$answer` should be available in global scope unless that if is inside a function.

Comment: It works for me. $abc is passed. Just check whether ur includeFile.php is in the same directory in which Main.php is present.

Comment: do you get any error, like $abc is undefined ? also try to var_dump($abc) in your IncludeFile.php

Comment: Nothing. I'm just not sure how to pass the global value or function. Googled around and couldnt find a solution. Any help please?